# Unable to track the import image task in AWS via cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am trying to .ova image using cli. The import-image command is working fine.

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "AppGate" --disk-containers file://container.json --region us-east-2
```

Output:

```
{
    "Status": "active",
    "Description": "AppGate",
    "SnapshotDetails": [
        {
            "UserBucket": {
                "S3Bucket": "appgatewayextdev",
                "S3Key": "app-gateway-19.2.1-1.0.0.ova"
            },
            "DiskImageSize": 0.0,
            "Format": "OVA"
        }
    ],
    "Progress": "2",
    "StatusMessage": "pending",
    "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-00625783cb8c9e528"
}
```

But when I try to use the describe-import-image-tasks  to track the above import task, it gives an unexpected error.

```
aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids  import-ami-00625783cb8c9e528

An error occurred (InvalidConversionTaskId.Malformed) when calling the DescribeImportImageTasks operation: Tasks import-ami-00625783cb8c9e528 not found
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: Make sure ami-00625783cb8c9e528 is exist

Comment: You have not supplied the --region parameter to the second query. I think your default region is not set to us-east-2 where you initiated the import image query.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue and my problem was that I did not meet the prerrequisites AWS demands before importing the image.

In my case I did have the service role but the image was not in the right bucket.

Please check this aws documentation:

[Import your VM as an image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-image-prereqs)
[VM Import/Export Requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-image-prereqs)